# Sync data between Exchange Office 365 and On-premise Exchange Server 2016

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchange-2016

I'm looking for some advises to know if it is factible to install an Exchange Server 2016 on-premise and if there is a proper way to implement it with a hybrid solution.

First of all, our customer is an office from a multinational company and it has a responsible for email accounts globally. Recenently, he adopted Office 365 with Exchange in cloud with 50GB mailbox per account.

The problem is that our customer receives to many emails internally and externally on each account. After uploading their PST files from the old email system to Exchange and after 2 years of usage, they reached those 50GB. Currently, we are saving old emails into a backup PST file that they can use to find and filter old emails, but they doesn't like that. They prefer having everything in the same folder. Also, they refuse to delete old emails, because they lack on a CRM system and they need to store the email information from customers.

Another problem is that we do not have access to manage those email acounts, because as I mentioned, those accounts are managed globaly by the company responsible. What we were thinking, and we do not know if it is possible to achieve, is to provide a hybrid solution "linking" accounts. For example:

> Exchange Office 365
>
> User: user@contoso.com
>
> Exchange On-Premise
>
> User: user@contoso.com
>
> A user sends an email to user@contoso.com, Office 365 receives it and
>   it is automatically downloaded to the **On-Premise** server with the same
>   account. When the process is done, the user, that is connected to the
>   **On-Premise** server, receives the email and it is removed from Office
>   365 (like a POP3). When user wants to send an email, the **On-Premise**
>   server sends a request to the Exchange Office 365 to send an email to
>   the desired account.

More or less is what we want to achieve. Is it possible or is the hybrid solution only working for staged migrations?

Comment: What you should recommend is Exchange Online Archiving for those users that need it. - https://products.office.com/en-US/exchange/microsoft-exchange-online-archiving-email

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks for the suggestion, but that is something the email responsible of the company should do, and it is not going to help that way. In fact, when our customer asked to him about mailboxes being full, the answer was: delete emails. So he is not going to help at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your customer is one office inside a large multi-national corporation and the people who are responsible for the email systems have told this office that they should delete emails.

How do you think you're going to be allowed to install an Exchange server in this environment? Do you think that you'll be able to do it without anyone knowing about it?

If the answer from corporate is to delete emails then that's what the customer should do. Otherwise they should present their case to the corporation on why that is not a good solution and ask the corporation for an acceptable solution.

Comment: It is more complex than that. The corporation says: delete emails. But if they want to add something externally (e.g. installing an exchange server on premise) they can do it without restrictions, but they must pay for it, they will no receive money from corporation. The corporation doesnt care if they set up an exchange server locally, but my problem is that they will probably not allow to link exchange accounts. Our first approach was to use an exchange server to "backup" emails on server instead of using PST stored in their current server through network share and they move emails.